# Split expressions with parentheses in align environment

Tags: math-mode, align

I am writing down a rather long expression, which has to be splitted in a `align` environment. The thing is that this expression has parentheses which have to be splitted too. I don't want to use `resizebox`, as this won't look pretty. My code is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\bullet \int\limits_V\!G(\mathbf{x,x^\prime})\rho(\mathbf{x^\prime})\;\diff^3x=&     \sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{Q}{8\pi^2R^2(2l+1)}\cdot\left(\int\limits_{a}^{b}\!\left[r_{<}^l-    \dfrac{a^{2l+1}}{r_<^{l+1}}\right]\left[\dfrac{1}{r_<}-\dfrac{r_<^l}    {b^{2l+1}}\right]\delta(r-R)\;\diff r\right)\\
    \cdot &     \left(\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\!P_l(\cos{\theta^\prime})P_l(\cos{\theta})\cos{\theta}\;\diff     \theta\right)\cdot \underbrace{\left(\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\!\diff \phi\right)}_{2\pi}\\
    =& \sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{Q}{4\pi R^2(2l+1)}\cdot \left(     \int\limits_{a}^{R}\!\left[r_{<}^l-\dfrac{a^{2l+1}}{r_<^{l+1}}\right]\left[\dfrac{1}{r_<}-    \dfrac{r_<^l}{b^{2l+1}}\right]\delta(r-R)\;\diff r_<\\
    +& \int\limits_{R}^{b}\!\left[r_{<}^l-\dfrac{a^{2l+1}}{r_<^{l+1}}\right]\left[\dfrac{1}    {r_<}-\dfrac{r_<^l}{b^{2l+1}}\right]\delta(r-R)\;\diff r_> \right)\\%here's the error 
    \cdot &     \left(P_l(\cos{\theta^\prime})\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}P_l(\cos{\theta})\underbrace{\cos{\theta    }}_{P_1}\;\diff\theta\right)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

My output is

[image]

Comment: You might be aware of the usage `\left( ... \right.` to suppress one side of the delimiters.

Comment: @percusse: I don't understand what you are trying to say...

Comment: You can leave left parenthesis on the first line and right parenthesis on the second line without scaling.

Comment: @percusse: I see! Now it's working, but it's not pretty in the eyes... I used `\bigg` which makes it better looking! Thank's!!!

Comment: I agree some expressions are just impossible to beautify. So the only thing that matters is that it's not ambiguous.

Comment: @percusse: I think I can live with that! Thank you once more for your help!

Comment: My pleasure. Do you mind answering this question since you have the working code now?

Comment: @percusse there are those, but with enough some attention to detail you can get most formulas nice including this one. Of course the question is always where to stop ... after all content is more important than form.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach I can only agree with that.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The commands `\left` and `\right` have to appear always in pairs within a single alignment cell. For this reason it is not possible to split them over several lines.

To achieve the desired outcome, you have two possibilities: one is to use to make artificial pairs by using an empty delimiter denoted by `.`, e.g., `\left( formula \right.` and on the next line `\left. formula \right)`. The problem here is that you may end up with differently sized parentheses if your formulas have different heights (in your example I guess you are ok).

The alternative is to choose the delimiter size manually using `\bigl`, `\Bigl`, `\biggl`, or `\Biggl` instead of `\left` and `\bigr`, etc. instead of `\right`.
Do not just use `\bigg` without the "l" or "r" as this changes the parentheses to an ordinary symbol instead of a `mathopen` or `mathclose` atom and that changes the spacing!

There are a few things not quite correct in your formula:

- in `amsmath` alignment should be specified to the left of the relational symbol, i.e., `&=` not `=&`
- I replaced most of the `\left/\right`in favor of explicit delimiters as the parentheses should not get bigger than the integrals
- On continuation lines one can use `\phantom` to move the second line inwards. This is a bit tricky and may require using `\mathrel` as well to tell LaTeX that something is still a relation, but it is worth the effort in the quality of the output.
- It may be worth the time to read up a good documentation on the `amsmath` package if you typeset this kind of formulas.
- One final advice: while you can't leave empty lines in formulas there is no reason not to split it in the source over many lines as this makes understanding and editing it much easier :-)

So here is my version of your formula (not beautifully layed out on the input but perhaps a little better already):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
             \bullet \int\limits_V\!G(\mathbf{x,x^\prime})\rho(\mathbf{x^\prime})\;\diff^3x
    &=     \sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{Q}{8\pi^2R^2(2l+1)}
             \cdot \Biggl(\int\limits_{a}^{b}\!\left[r_{<}^l -   
                    \dfrac{a^{2l+1}}{r_<^{l+1}}\right]\left[\dfrac{1}    
                    {r_<}-\dfrac{r_<^l}    {b^{2l+1}}\right]\delta(r-R)\;\diff r\Biggr)
\\
    &\mathrel{\phantom{=}}   % <--- this makes space of a relational =
             \mathrel\cdot            % <--- tricky this is no longer considered a relation because of the phantom above  
      \Biggl( \int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\!P_l(\cos{\theta^\prime})P_l(\cos{\theta})\cos{\theta}\;\diff     
                                      \theta\Biggr)
           \cdot  \underbrace{\left(\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\!\diff \phi\right)}_{2\pi}
\\
    &= \sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{Q}{4\pi R^2(2l+1)}\cdot 
           \Biggl(     \int\limits_{a}^{R}\!\left[r_{<}^l-\dfrac{a^{2l+1}}{r_<^{l+1}}\right]\left[\dfrac{1}{r_<}
                  -    \dfrac{r_<^l}{b^{2l+1}}\right]\delta(r-R)\;\diff r_<
\\
    &\phantom{=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{Q}{4\pi R^2(2l+1)}\cdot\Biggl(}   % <--- this makes space!
       +\int\limits_{R}^{b}\!\left[r_{<}^l-\dfrac{a^{2l+1}}{r_<^{l+1}}\right]\left[\dfrac{1}    {r_<}
        -\dfrac{r_<^l}{b^{2l+1}}\right]\delta(r-R)\;\diff r_> \Biggr)
\\
    &\mathrel{\phantom{=}}
        \mathrel\cdot    
       \Biggl(P_l(\cos{\theta^\prime})\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}P_l(\cos{\theta})\underbrace{\cos{\theta    }}_{P_1}\;\diff\theta\Biggr)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

And here is the result--enjoy:

[image]

just noticed I forgot to change `\left/\right` in the underbrace part ... well :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!!! Would it be OK if I edited your answer just to add the working code as well as it's output?

Comment: in a minute ...

Comment: I think that you, @Thanos, should add `\;` to the definition of `\diff`, as you use it always. And may be, you would like to use `\begin{multlined}[t] … \end{multlined}` from the `mathtools` package.

Comment: Not the point of the question, but can someone explain the claim “in `amsmath` alignment should be specified to the left of the relational symbol, i.e., `&=` not `=&`”. Why would `amsmath` determine where the author wants to align the equation?

Comment: @RandyCragun it doesn't, what I mean is that the point of alignment is to the right of `&`, so if you want elsewhere you put it elsewhere but you still have to put it to the left of whatever you want to see aligned.