# Where is the error that i can not run?

Tags: math-mode, align

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}\usepackage{amssymb}
\textwidth=16.5cm  \oddsidemargin=-0.10cm \evensidemargin=-0.10cm  \topmargin=-1.0cm \textheight=24.5cm

\newcommand{\piRsquare}{\pi r^2}        

\title{The small amplitude expansion: The class of theoritical considered}
\author{xxx }       
\date{January 26, 2013}                 
\begin{document} \baselineskip=18pt
\section{Introduction}
\section{Reconstruction of the article equation(15) }

Given, $$\phi_1= p_1cos(\tau+\alpha)$$
$$\nabla\phi_1= -p_1sin(\tau+\alpha) \nabla \alpha+\nabla p_1cos(\tau+\alpha)$$
$$\Delta\phi_1= -p_1 \nabla \alpha \cos(\tau+\alpha) \nabla \alpha-p_1 sin(\tau+\alpha) \Delta\alpha -\nabla \alpha \sin(\tau+\alpha)\nabla p_1-\nabla p_1 \nabla \alpha sin(\tau+ \alpha)+\Delta p_1cos(\tau+\alpha)$$
$$\Delta\phi_1= \cos(\tau+\alpha) [-p_1 \Delta \alpha + \Delta p_1]- sin(\tau+\alpha) [p_1\Delta \alpha+2\nabla \alpha \nabla p_1]$$
 Differentiating $\phi_1$,
$$\phi_1= p_1cos(\tau+\alpha)$$
$$\dot\phi_1= -p_1 sin(\tau+\alpha)$$
$$\ddot\phi_1= -p_1cos(\tau+\alpha)$$
Again,
$$\phi_2 = p_2\cos(\tau + \alpha) + q_2\sin(\tau + \alpha) + \frac{g_2}{6}p_1^2[\cos(2\tau + 2\alpha) - 3] $$
$\omega_1=0$ for the bounding conditions.
$$\dot\phi_2 = -p_2\sin(\tau + \alpha) + q_2\cos(\tau + \alpha) + \frac{g_2}{6}p_1^2[-2 \sin(2\tau + 2\alpha) ] $$
$$\ddot\phi_2 = -p_2\cos(\tau + \alpha)- q_2\sin(\tau + \alpha) - \frac{4g_2}{6}p_1^2[\cos(2\tau + 2\alpha) ] $$
Putting these values in equation,
\begin{align*}
 &\ddot\phi_3+\phi_3+2g_2\phi_1\phi_2+g_3\phi_1^3-\ddot\phi_1-\Delta\phi_1
   +\omega_1\ddot\phi_2+\omega_2\ddot\phi_1 =0
\\[\bigskipamount]
&\begin{aligned}
 &\ddot\phi_3+\phi_3+2g_2p_1 \cos(\tau+\alpha)
  [p_2\cos(\tau + \alpha)  + q_2\sin(\tau + \alpha) +
   \frac{g_2}{6}p_1^2[\cos(2\tau + 2\alpha) - 3]] \\
  &\quad{}+g_3p^3_1\cos^3(\tau+\alpha)
    +p_1\cos(\tau+\alpha)-\cos(\tau+\alpha) [-p_1 \Delta \alpha+\Delta p_1] \\
  &\quad {}-\sin(\tau+\alpha) [p_1\Delta \alpha+2\nabla \alpha \nabla p_1]
    +\omega_2p_1\cos(\tau+\alpha)=0 \\
\end{aligned}
\\[\bigskipamount]
&\begin{aligned}
 &\ddot\phi_3+\phi_3+g_2p_1 p_2 [1+\cos2(\tau+\alpha)]
  + g_2p_1 q_2\sin2(\tau+\alpha) \\
 &\quad{} + \frac{2 g_2^2 p_1^3}{6} \cos(\tau +\alpha)[2\cos^2(\tau+\alpha)-4] \\
 &\quad{} + g_3p_1^3[\frac{1}{4}(3\cos(\tau +\alpha)+\cos3(\tau+\alpha))]
          + p_1\cos(\tau+\alpha) \\
 &\quad{} -\cos(\tau+\alpha)[\Delta p_1-p_1 \Delta\alpha]
          +\sin(\tau+\alpha)[p_1\Delta \alpha+2 \nabla p_1 \nabla \alpha]
           \omega_2p_1\cos(\tau+\alpha) =0
\end{aligned}
\\[\bigskipamount]
&\begin{aligned}
 & \ddot\phi_3+\phi_3+g_2p_1 p_2 + g_2p_1 p_2  cos2(\tau+\alpha)] + g_2p_1 q_2sin2(\tau+\alpha)  \\
 &\quad{} + \frac{2 g_2^2 p_1^3}{3} cos^3(\tau +\alpha)-\frac{8 g_2^2 p_1^3}{6} cos(\tau +\alpha)+g_3p_1^3[\frac{1}{4}(3cos(\tau +\alpha)+cos3(\tau+\alpha))] \\
 &\quad{} +p_1cos(\tau+\alpha)-cos(\tau+\alpha)[\Delta p_1-p_1 \Delta \alpha]+sin(\tau+\alpha)[p_1\Delta \alpha+2 \nabla p_1 \nabla \alpha]+\omega_2p_1cos(\tau+\alpha)=0
\end{aligned}
\\[\bigskipamount]
&\begin{aligned}
 & \ddot\phi_3+\phi_3+g_2p_1 p_2 + g_2p_1 p_2  cos2(\tau+\alpha)] + g_2p_1 q_2sin2(\tau+\alpha)  \\
 &\quad{} + \frac{2 g_2^2 p_1^3}{3}[\frac{1}{4}(3cos(\tau +\alpha)+cos3(\tau+\alpha))] -\frac{8 g_2^2 p_1^3}{6} cos(\tau +\alpha)+g_3p_1^3[\frac{1}{4}(3cos(\tau +\alpha)+cos3(\tau+\alpha))] \\
 &\quad{} +p_1cos(\tau+\alpha)-cos(\tau+\alpha)[\Delta p_1-p_1 \Delta\ alpha]+sin(\tau+\alpha)[p_1\Delta \alpha+2 \nabla p_1 \nabla \alpha]+\omega_2p_1cos(\tau+\alpha)=0 \\
\end{aligned}
\\[\bigskipamount]
&\begin{aligned}
 & \ddot\phi_3+\phi_3+sin(\tau+\alpha)[p_1\Delta \alpha+2 \nabla p_1 \nabla \alpha] -cox(\tau+ \alpha)[\nabla p_1\\
 &\quad{} -p_1\nabla \alpha+\frac{5}{6}g_2^2p_1^3- \frac{3}{4}g_3p_1^3-p_1 +\omega_2 p_1] \\
 &\quad{} +\frac{ p_1^3}{12}(2g_2^2+3g_3)cos3(\tau + \alpha)+g_2 p_1 [p_2+ p_2 cos2(\tau +\alpha)+q_2 sin2(\tau+\alpha)] =0\\
\end{aligned}
\\[\bigskipamount]
&\begin{aligned}
 & \ddot\phi_3+\phi_3+sin(\tau+\alpha)[p_1\Delta \alpha+2 \nabla p_1 \nabla \alpha] -cox(\tau+ \alpha)[\Delta p_1-p_1\nabla \alpha \\
 &\quad{} + \lambda p_1^3-p_1+\omega_2 p_1] +\frac{p_1^3}{12}(2g_2^2+3g_3)cos3(\tau + \alpha) \\
 &\quad{} +g_2 p_1 [p_2+ p_2 cos2(\tau +\alpha)+q_2 sin2(\tau+\alpha)]=0
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, reduce the code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), you may even find the error yourself then. Also, don't use `$$ ...$$` (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503). For several consecutive equations, use `gather` or `align`.

Comment: Is the problem  solved?

Comment: You can't use ``\\`` between ``\left[`` and ``\right]``. That is atleast one problem I saw.

Comment: I don't think there is a major problem in my tex file. Just look for a while please.

Comment: If the problem is solved then, post it as answer.

Comment: The only thing preventing your document from compiling is what myrtille mentions in her answer and Christian R. in his comment. There are other issues though (such as those mentioned I mentioned above), but they do not prevent compilation.

Comment: Some other questions related to your problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89615/split-expressions-with-parentheses-in-align-environment?rq=1 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21290/how-to-make-left-right-pairs-of-delimiter-work-over-multiple-lines/21294#21294

Comment: @All: Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in it's current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Also, if you downvote, please leave a comment explaining why you did so.

Comment: I don't understand this question (and have not voted, yet).  The posted code compiles without error, i.e. no complaint from the latex processor.  (The formatting is extremely bad, but that is partly addressed in another question.)  There is no `\left/\right` in the code, mentioned in the comments or the answer.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Look at the revision history, the original question had `\left[ ... \right]`. Why the OP removed them, I do not know.

Comment: Going strictly by the title (there is no other information than the code) I agree with @AndrewSwann.  The code compiles -- no errors.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, I see, they are there somewhere in the revision history.  However, it is not easy to find - over 800 characters have changed on each revision - and now we have a posting that is confusing.  I have voted to close as "too localised".

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `\right.` and `\left.` when you want to have a parenthesis that spans several lines:

```
\begin{align*}
&\begin{aligned}
&-Acosx- Bsinx -9Ccos3x-9Dsin3x-4Ecos2x-4Fsin2x+Acosx+ Bsinx +Ccos3x+Dsin3x\\
 &\quad{}+Ecos2x+Fsin2x+G+(p_1\Delta\alpha+2\nabla\alpha\nabla p_1)\sin(\tau+\alpha)-\left[\Delta p_1+\omega_2p_1+\lambda p_1^3+\right.\\
&\left.\quad{}-p_1(\nabla\alpha)^2\right]\cos(\tau+\alpha)+\frac{1}{12}p_1^3(2g_2^2+3g_3)\cos(3\tau+3\alpha)+g_2p_1\left[q_2\sin(2\tau+2\alpha)+p_2\cos(2\tau+2\alpha)+p_2\right] =0
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}
```

Comment: This doesn't necessarily lead to equal sized parenthesis, as the scaling only takes into account the symbols on the current line. May be better to use `\biggl` and `\biggr` (or one of the similar commands) instead of `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: To be honest I didn't look at the output after "fixing" the compilation error. Now that I have, I have to say the size of his parenthesis is probably the least of his problems, the equation is not just reaching into the margins, it's actually going on well beyond the end of the page for quite a number of equations. Lot of work to be done there.