# Only left brace or bar in math equations

Tags: math-mode, equations, braces

I wanna insert only a left bar like `\left |` without the closing right bar.

Why?
I want to use it as separator of calculation hints.

`$a * b = c | :b\\
a = \frac{c}{b}$`

and so on.

It must be a left bar and not only `|` or `\vert` so that it is scaled in height.

Comment: Use `$ a * b = \left. c \right| :b [and so on]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single `.` can be used as the partner of a bracket, e.g.:

```
\left| \frac{b}{c} \right.
\left. \frac{b}{c} \right|
```

There is also `\middle` in order to scale something in the middle of an expression, e.g.:

```
\left. a * b = c \middle| :b \right.
```

However, in your case, probably you should use some way to align your computation across several lines.  This can be done using, for example, the environment `align` from package `amsmath`:

```
\begin{align}
    a * b &= c   &&| :b\\
    a     &= \frac{c}{b}
\end{align}
```

This will, however, lead to the problem that you cannot use `\left` and `\right` across different cells of an `align`, as explained at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89621/88939.

Comment: One can of course always use the manual size commands.

Comment: @moewe yes, that's part of the answer in the link.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for that late reply, I thought I'll get an email after an answer.